# dropwizard + auto-reconnect + postgres + mybatis

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, dropwizard

I'm using latest dropwizard and Postgres database with the iBatis framework, and I noticed the application dies if the Postgres server is restarted. Is there a configuration setting or code I can add so that it will try re-connecting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the secret sauce was to add:

checkConnectionOnReturn: true

to my config